# How can I see the numerical value of the Repeat delay keyboard setting?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

Is there any way I can see the current numerical value of this setting? I would like to see the difference between the 4 available ticks.

[image: Repeat delay Setting]

Answer (score 0):

For non-USB keyboards, the values are 1 second, 3/4 second, 1/2 second, and 1/4 second. See [Keyboard commands - Command f3: Set repeat rate and delay](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-12.html#kcf3) from [Keyboard scancodes](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes.html) by Andries Brouwer